# to delete a page's anchor's link from page's url

Tags: javascript, html

`file:///portfolio/index.html#wrapper`

It is the first page's link and `#wrapper` in the end, is an anchor (specific part of page) in this page.
On this specific part, there is a link to second page. I click the link and go to the second page but when click the browser's back button
it backs to the specific part of first page but I want to delete the `#wrapper` from page's link to back to top of the page.
How can I do this (by browser's back button)?!

Comment: show us your code!!!!

Comment: If you navigate to "index.htm#wrapper", go somewhere else and go back, you go back to "index.htm#wrapper". You can't change it. What you could do is go to #wrapper via javascript, in that case the url wouldn't change at all.

Comment: Why would you want to? That's where the user was -- at that anchor. I, as a user, expect that when I click the back button, I'm taken back to to point on the previous page where I left it. Don't mess with users' expectations or suffer the consequences. (read [Don't Make Me Think by Steve Krug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Make_Me_Think)).

Comment: cause the page does not scroll when back to the anchor

Answer (score 0):

You can't override browser's "back button", there isn't any function to do things like this in javascript.
But there is a JavaScript library that will help you doing this, which is called [Really simple history](https://code.google.com/archive/p/reallysimplehistory/)
And [this](https://github.com/BradNeuberg/rsh#demos-and-examples) will help you.